# .NET Maui pass data from MainActivity.cs to a view model in order to display it

Tags: android, .net, maui

I have a string variable in my Android platform-specific code file MainActivity.cs.
I also have a view model binded with a view that has just a single label.

How do I pass this string variable from MainActivity.cs to my view model?

```
                                                                                                                                  ....
```

Comment: is the string value set at startup?  Or do you need to update it after the app has started?

Comment: @Jason The string initially is set to null then it gets a value from a function

Answer (score 0):

A simple method is to use [Publish and subscribe to messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/messagingcenter) to achieve this.
You can subscribe to a message in your viewmodel and publish a message in the `MainActivity.cs`.

But as the note mentioned that

> `MessagingCenter` has been deprecated in .NET 7 and replaced with
> `WeakReferenceMessenger` in the [CommunityToolkit.Mvvm](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommunityToolkit.Mvvm) NuGet package.

And from document [Messenger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/messenger),we could know that you can send and receive messages with the following code:

```
 // Create a message in your app
public class MyMessage : ValueChangedMessage<string>
{
    public MyMessage(string value): base(value)
    {        
    }
}

// Register a message in your view model
WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<MyMessage>(this, (r, m) =>
{
    // Handle the message here, with r being the recipient and m being the
    // input message. Using the recipient passed as input makes it so that
    // the lambda expression doesn't capture "this", improving performance.

      var receivedstring = m.value;
});

// Send a message from `MainActivity.cs`
WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new MyMessage("test string"));
```

Comment: Hi @taqasar-elcam, may I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.